# Smart chaining operator in Haskell for DSL purpose

Tags: haskell, operators, dsl

I have a `State` sum type, and I need to evaluate the validity of sequences in a list of such states:

```hs
data State = Running | Idle | Stopped | Heating | Broken | Paused | Starting | Stopping
seq = [Stopped, Starting, Running, Paused, Running, Idle, Stopping, Stopped]
```

For every element of `seq`, I need to assess whether it's compatible with one or more items that precede it. It is fairly easy to do by, for every `i` of `seq`, checking the values of `seq !! (i-1)` and (optionally) `seq !! (i-2)`.

However, for readability and maintenance purposes, I'm trying to build a mini-DSL based on a chaining operator so that for every element in `seq`, I can assess whether it is valid or not, depending on the sequence that precedes it.

Following the toy example below:

```hs
-- current/naive implementation
-- (real-world follows the same model but is much more complex)
isValid :: [State] -> Int -> Bool
isValid seq i =
      ite (curr == Running)    (prev1 `elem` [Starting, Idle, Paused])
    $ ite (curr == Idle)       (prev2 `elem` [Paused] && prev1 `elem` [Running])
    $ ite (curr == Broken)     (prev3 `elem` [Running] && prev2 `elem` [Heating] && prev1 `elem` [Heating])
    $ False
    where curr  = seq !! i
          prev1 = seq !! (i-1)
          prev2 = seq !! (i-2)

-- "ideal" implementation using a (|>) chaining operator
-- (with some syntactic liberties)
isValid :: [State] -> Int -> Bool
isValid seq i =
      Running  =>  [Starting, Idle, Paused]
    $ Idle     =>  [Paused]  |> [Running]
    $ Broken   =>  [Running] |> [Heating] |> [Heating]
    where (=>) curr prev   = -- ...
          (|>) prev1 prev2 = -- ...
```

The part I'm struggling the most with is, how to ensure that `(|>)` understands if it has to lookup `i-1` versus `i-2` or `i-3` depending on how many times it's chained, so that:

```hs
[Starting]                         -- seq !! (i-1) == Starting
[Starting] |> [Running]            -- seq !! (i-2) == Starting && seq !! (i-1) == Running
[Starting] |> [Running] |> [Idle]  -- seq !! (i-3) == Starting && seq !! (i-2) == Running && seq !! (i-1) == Idle
```

I'm not specially attached to following **exactly** as much syntactic sugar as in the "ideal" version above, but any idea or approach that could get closer to it would be welcome.

Comment: Not a complete answer, but since this is a sequence recognition problem, I’d recommend using a parsing library. E.g. with [`regex-applicative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-applicative), you might write something like ``(sym Running *> psym (`elem` [Starting, Idle, Paused]) *> pure ()) <|> (sym Idle *> sym Running *> sym Paused *> pure ()) <|> …`` and use `many` to greedily match the whole sequence (reversed). You could use nearly the same code with most parser combinator libraries, or roll your own `ExceptT String (State [State])`, but that’s more involved & probably overkill.

Answer (score 4):

Your DSL is a language of *predicates* (they say whether something is true or false) on a *context* (they are evaluated on varying parts of the input).

In particular, the *context* consists of the input, and an index into it:

```
type Context = ([State], Int)
type Predicate = Context -> Bool
```

Then we can work on the language top-down, inspecting the definition of `isValid` from the root. First, it is a sequence of predicates. As you've noticed each line is a logical implication, and you want the predicate to fail if any of the implications are broken. So we start with conjunction of predicates:

```hs
infixr 4 &&.
(&&.) :: Predicate -> Predicate -> Predicate
p &&. q = \c -> p c && q c
```

Implication can be defined similarly, the corresponding boolean operation coincides with the `Ord` operation `(<=)`.

```hs
(=>.) :: Predicate -> Predicate -> Predicate
p =>. q = \c -> p c <= q c
```

In your proposed syntax, the left-hand side of `(=>)` is actually not a `Predicate`, but a `State`. You can decompose that into the binary operation `(=>.)` on predicates we just defined, plus an operation to view states as predicates. When you write `Running => ...`, you are trying to say that "if the current state is `Running`, then ...". So a state `s` corresponds to the predicate "the current state is `s`":

```
current :: State -> Predicate
current s = \(seq, i) ->
  -- Naive version: (seq !! i) == s
  index i seq == Just s

-- Total indexing function
index :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
index i seq = listToMaybe (drop i seq)
```

We also want to talk about states before the current one. One way is to transform a predicate to evaluate it in a modified context that points to the previous state:

```
prev :: Predicate -> Predicate
prev p = \(seq, i) -> p (seq, i-1)
```

On the right-hand side you also have lists of states, meaning a predicate that matches if the current state is any of them:

```
currentIn :: [State] -> Predicate
currentIn ss = \(seq, i) ->
  case index i seq of
    Nothing -> False
    Just s -> s `elem` ss
```

With all of those basic building blocks, we can build higher-level combinators that are closer to the syntax you were looking for.

`(|>)` looks up the current state in a list (the first argument), and shifts its second argument back in time:

```
infixr 9 |>
(|>) :: [State] -> Predicate -> Predicate
ss |> q = currentIn ss &&. prev q

-- End delimiter/identity element for `(|>)`
true :: Predicate
true = \_ -> True
```

`(=>+)` is an implication with a state on its left, but also shifting the second argument to start looking at the previous state directly (avoiding the reserved syntax `=>`)

```
infixr 8 =>+
(=>+) :: State -> Predicate -> Predicate
s =>+ q = current s &&. prev q
```

The relevant operations for your example are `(&&.)`, `(|>)`, `(=>+)`, and we can be careful about operator precedence to avoid parentheses.

```
isValid :: Predicate
isValid =
        Running  =>+  [Starting, Idle, Paused] |> true
    &&. Idle     =>+  [Paused]  |> [Running] |> true
    &&. Broken   =>+  [Running] |> [Heating] |> [Heating] |> true
```

Finally, we need to generate all relevant contexts from a sequence, to validate a whole sequence:

```
allContexts :: [State] -> [Context]
allContexts seq = [(seq, i) | i <- [0 .. length seq - 1]]

validate :: [State] -> Bool
validate seq = all isValid (allContexts seq)
```

That should be enough to get things working, but one big complaint one may have is that all those list lookups are expensive. It will be much more efficient to change the representation of the context to something that fits the DSL operations better. Notably, we want to be able to look at the current state, and those preceding it. A much better representation should thus make those available more directly:

```
type Context = [State]  -- A reversed prefix of the whole sequence, so the current state is at the head, and other states precede it.
-- Example:
-- - Old context: ([a,b,c,d,e], 1)    ("the element at position 1 in the list [a,b,c,d,e]")
-- - New context: [b,a]

allContexts :: [State] -> [Context]
allContexts seq = init (tails (reverse seq))  -- non-empty prefixes, reversed
```

You have to update all the combinators, but the definition of `isValid` should remain unchanged. (Exercise for the reader.)

Answer (score 3):

Consider processing your list in reverse, and using `tails` to get prefixes. So:

```
isValidPrefix :: [State] -> Bool
isValidPrefix seq = case seq of
    Running:prev:_ -> prev `elem` [Starting, Idle, Paused]
    Idle:Paused:Running:_ -> True
    Broken:Running:Heating:Heating:_ -> True
    [] -> True -- presumably?
    [_] -> True -- also presumed
    _ -> False

isValidSequence :: [State] -> Bool
isValidSequence = all isValidPrefix . tails . reverse
```